# multiple $cordovaInAppBrowser in controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Can i have multiple $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){}); in my controller.js ? I need to do javascript injection on different url.

Answer (score 0):

your event contains url property . use that with a switch statement.